# Python compare text from first column of two documents

Tags: python, compare

Help on Python script needed as I'm completely new to this !

I have two text documents as below and want to look if the elements on Column A from file1 are present somewhere on column A from file2. Columns are separated by TAB. Text on other columns doesn't matter.

File1

```
1  test
4  sample
10 abc
7  text
```

File2

```
2  abs
10 abj
1  test
32 python
```

And the desired output would be

```
1
10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_col1_elems(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        return [line.split()[0] for line in f.readlines()]
        
for item in [i for i in get_col1_elems('file1.txt') if i in get_col1_elems('file2.txt')]:
    print(item)
```

Verbose version for explanatory purposes as requested

```
def get_col1_elems(file_name):
    col1_elems = []
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            all_line_elements = line.split()
            first_line_element = all_line_elements[0]
            col1_elems.append(first_line_element)
    return col1_elems

file1_list = get_col1_elems('file1.txt')
file2_list = get_col1_elems('file2.txt')
items_in_both_lists = []

for i in file1_list:
    if i in file2_list:
        items_in_both_lists.append(i)

for items in items_in_both_lists:
    print(item)
```

Comment: Works fine! Though that loop is a bit confusing for me. is there a way to write it in a more verbose way so that i can understand the logic behind?

Comment: Verbose version added - hope it helps!